# Xpages File Download collect and display extra information

Tags: file-upload, download, xpages

I'm using file upload and download control. I understand how to use the provided display columns, but how would I go about collecting other info about each uploaded file and then displaying it (i.e. Display Name and Notes that the user would enter)?

```
<xp:fileUpload id="fileUpload1"
                                value="#{document1.files}" style="width:80%"
                                useUploadname="false">


                                <xp:eventHandler event="onchange"
                                    submit="true" refreshMode="complete"
                                    disableValidators="true">
                                </xp:eventHandler>
                            </xp:fileUpload>
                            <xp:br></xp:br>

                            <xp:fileDownload rows="30" id="FD1"
                                displayLastModified="false" value="#{document1.files}"
                                style="width:98%" hideWhen="true" displayType="false"
                                displayCreated="true" rules="all"
                                lastModifiedTitle="Last Modified">

                                <xp:this.allowDelete><![CDATA[${javascript:database.queryAccessRoles(session.getEffectiveUserName()).contains('[Admin]')}]]></xp:this.allowDelete>
                            </xp:fileDownload>
```

Comment: "Notes" about the attachment - where you want to store such notes? You have few options (dedicated document for every attachment with Notes field in them, or multivalue field with attachment name=>notes pairs and so on), so update your question, what is your intent.

Comment: FK: I was thinking to just keep the notes and title pertaining to each attachment in the main document, but I'm thinking your suggestion to store each attachment in its own doc.

Comment: You may start here https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Multi%20Attachment%20Custom%20Control and customize it to store the notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly: you want to add additional information columns into the file download control that are derived from information stored or computed elsewhere, e.g. from a NotesItem (a field in the Notes document)?

In this case you need to construct your own output using a repeat control. You can render a table or a list - whatever you deem fit for display.

The “trick” is how to construct the URL for download - which is simply:

```
/yourdatabase.nsf/0/unid/AttachmentName?OpenAttachment
```

(typed off memory. You might need to double check syntax).

Word of caution: if you have lots of attachments, you might consider having separate documents for them and use a view - above URL works in views too. Saves you a versioning headache (in case multiple users can upload to the same document).

Let us know how it goes

Comment: STWISSEL: I am likely to have many attachments on each. So, again, probably having separate docs is a good idea. I have to admit, though, I've been an Xpages developer for a long time now, and I've never been able to use a repeat control successfully. I usually just embed a view panel, but I'd really like the idea of a repeat control. 1. How do you make attachments save as their own documents? use createDocument()? AND 2. Do you know of a simple example of a repeat control?

Comment: How about a dojo grid?

Comment: Dojo grid needs to get data from somewhere - so you can use it, most likely need a repeat to feed it. I would stay clear of dojo as much as you can

Comment: Exercise 17 here: https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/m_Home.xsp?documentId=F96D8FAF55207C64852575F5007593FB#mobileViewer Pleading guilty: I wrote those exercises for 8.5.0

Comment: How do I get the Attachment name if I am storing the attachments in separate docs?

Comment: You make the documents you upload the attachments to response documents to the main doc

Comment: Been working on this for a while. I am not able to create a response document which contains the attachment. Even if I forget about the attachment and try to save one field to the response document, I get this error: Unable to create new document
NotesException: A required argument has not been provided